# assigning local variable to global variable in c++

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables

i have object

```
 template <class FLOAT>
 struct Cstruct {
       Struct1<FLOAT> _var1;
       Struct2<FLOAT> _var2;   
       Cstruct(){};
       Cstruct(Struct1 var1,Struct2 var2):_var1(var1),_var2(var2){};
};
```

FLOAT can be "double" or "int". Struct1 and Struct2 are also templatized with FLOAT.

now i also have a global variable declared

```
 Cstruct<double> globalObj_d;Cstruct<int> globalObj_i;
```

inside main() i have

```
main(){
  // some code
  if double then call func<double>();
  if int    then call func<int>();        

}
```

and inside templatized func() i have

```
template<class FLOAT> void func(){
 // some code 
 Struct1<FLOAT> var1;
 Struct2<FLOAT> var2;
 Cstruct<FLOAT> localObj(var1,var2);
 // now i want to assign "localObj" to the global object "globalObj_d"
 if double then 
     globalObj_d = localObj;
 if int then
     globalObj_i = localObj;
}
```

and i get an error saying

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Cstruct<FLOAT>
```

does does this mean i have to explicitly write an "operator=" inside Cstruct  ? my understading of templatized and global object it seems is kind of flawed. any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tell me what this does in C++: `if double then`. Seems you are talking different language.

Comment: if statement lines are not c++, i just gave pseudocode to explain the issue. i just created a example problem to demonstrate the issue i am facing.

Comment: I get error C2955: 'Struct1' : use of class template requires template argument list on the second CStruct constructor - is this exactly your code?

Comment: strange that you got error C2955. i get error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Cstruct<FLOAT>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) with FLOAT=int
         d:xxx.h(201):couldbe'Cstruct<FLOAT>&Cstruct<FLOAT>::operator =(Cstruct<FLOAT> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              FLOAT=double
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Cstruct<FLOAT>, Cstruct<FLOAT>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              FLOAT=double
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              FLOAT=int
1>          ]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might need to. See the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) The compiler will provide one for you if it can. You have not showed us the definitions of `Struct1<FLOAT>` or `Struct2<FLOAT>`. If it can't generate assignments for these, it can't generate one for `CStruct`.

While you are there, avoid the [leading underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996909/does-using-leading-underscores-actually-cause-trouble) on the variable names .

Comment: doesn't c++ generate default assignments ?

Comment: @user1612986:  It does in this case, unless something is not shown in the OP.

Comment: It does if it can - but we don't know if it can because we can't see Struct1 or Struct2.

Answer (score 0):

The use of psudocode in your question make it difficult to understand.  So let me try to boil this down a little bit in to real code.  It appears that what you are trying to do is essentially something along these lines:

```
template <typename VAL>
class Foo
{
public:
  VAL mVal;
};

int main()
{
  Foo <int> global_i;
  Foo <double> global_d;

  Foo <double> local;

  // ...
  if (/*someConditional*/)
    global_i = local;  // <== LINE 1
  else
    global_d = local;  // <== LINE 2
}
```

This won't work.  Note that even though only one of either `LINE1` or `LINE2`are executed at run-time, they are both compiled at compile-time.  The first one is trying to assign a `Foo<int>` to a `Foo<double>`, but the types are not compatible much in the same way that these are also not compatible:

```
class Gee
{
};

class Whiz
{
};

int main()
{
  Gee g;
  Whiz w;

  Gee local;
  local = w;  // <<< INCOMPATIBLE TYPES
}
```

In order to make this work, you will either need to provide some kind of conversion operator on `Foo` to convert to another type of `Foo`, for example:

```
template <typename VAL>
class Foo
{
public:
  template <typename OTHER> operator Foo <OTHER> () const 
  {
    Foo <OTHER> ret;
    // ...
    return ret;
   }
};
```

...or perhaps provide two separate functions to do the assignments; one for a `Foo<int>`, and another for a `Foo<double>`.

Comment: I read the  if part as being in a template, so the local is of type typename FLOAT, but the pseudocode is making this hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

First: if a type might be either floating point or integer, *don't* name it "FLOAT". You could use the standard `T`, or perhaps something like `Number`, but definitely avoid `FLOAT`.

As to the real question (or my guess at the real question): almost any time you think in terms of `if (type == X)` or `switch (type)` sort of code (at least in C++), you're making a fundamental mistake -- you *can* probably manage to do that if you want to badly enough, *but* it's not how C++ is intended to work.

In this case, there's a fairly easy way to avoid it: create another template. In particular, you can overload a couple of function templates, one for each global you want to support:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int i_global;
double d_global;

template <class T>
void assign(T in) { 
    // this function should never be called.
    assert(false);
}

template<>
void assign<int>(int in) { 
    i_global = in;
}

template<>
void assign<double>(double in) {
    d_global = in;
}

// for the moment, func(input) will just call assign(input):
template <class T>
void func(T input) {
    assign<T>(input);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: trash <number>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string in(argv[1]);

    // see if the input contains a decimal point, and act accordingly:
    if (in.find('.') != std::string::npos)
        func(std::stod(in));
    else
        func(std::stoi(in));

    // show the results -- the values of the globals:
    std::cout << "Result:\ndouble: " << d_global << "\nint: " << i_global << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the result I'd hope for -- if I enter something like `1.5` it gets assigned to the double; if I enter something like `123` it gets assigned to the `int`.